# Prove that a.e. convergence with bounded integral implies $L^1$ convergece

Tags: real-analysis

I'm preparing for an analysis qualifying exam so I am answering some old exam questions. Here's part of one stated below:

---

Suppose that $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ is a finite measure space, and that $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and $f$ are measurable functions on $X$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e.

Suppose there exists $C < \infty$ such that $\int f_n^2 d\mu \leq C$ for all $n \geq 1$. Show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$

---

I got to the point where I proved that $\{f_n\}$ and $f$ are $L^1$ functions whose integral is bounded by some $M < \infty$, taking into account that these functions possibly map to $\mathbb{C}$. So at the very least these functions exist in $L^1$ space.

Comment: The integral would be $0$. We can prove this using dominated convergence.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 why does $\int\limits_{X\backslash K}{|f-f_n|}$ go to zero? It doesn't follow directly from the fact that $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise on $X\backslash K$.

Comment: I have the same question as Joey. Pointwise convergence by itself does not imply convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: Yeah, no, I was being stupid. I think I misread the question somewhere. My apologies for the time wasted.

Comment: For a finite measure space, convergence a.e. implies convergence in measure. Split the space into two parts by $|f_n-f|>\epsilon$. Then the measure of this set goes 0, and as you have shown the integrand is bounded. The other part is bounded by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks Simo. I did attempt splitting the integral between $\{|f_n - f| \leq \epsilon\}$ and $\{|f_n - f| > \epsilon\}$, but I was having trouble with $\{|f_n - f| > \epsilon\}$. The integrand itself, $|f_n - f|$, is not necessarily bounded. I am just able to infer that $\int |f_n - f| \leq 2M$ for all $n$.

Comment: My previous comment did not work.  But I believe Jensen's inequality will do the trick: Let $A_k = \{x : |f_k(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}$. We know $|A_k|<\infty$.  If $|A_k|=0$ then $\int_{x \in A_k} |f_k(x)-f(x)|d\mu = 0$.  Else, you get $$\frac{1}{|A_k|}\int_{x \in A_k} |f_k-f|^2d\mu \geq \left( \frac{1}{|A_k|}\int_{x \in A_k} |f_k-f|d\mu \right)^2 \implies \int_{x \in A_k} |f_k-f|d\mu \leq \sqrt{D}\sqrt{|A_k|}$$ for some constant $D$ that upper-bounds $\int |f_k-f|^2$ (assuming you can prove that, indeed, $\int f^2 < \infty$).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the help guys! Here's my solution:

We want to show that $\int_X |f_n - f| d\mu \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

We will first show that each $|f_n - f| \in L^1$. Observe that $|f_n|^2 = Re(f_n^2)$, so that since $\int f_n^2 \leq C$ (no imaginary component), $\int |f_n|^2 = \int f_n^2 \leq C$. So $\int_X |f_n| d\mu = \int_{\{|f_n| \leq 1\}} |f_n| d\mu + \int_{\{|f_n| > 1\}} |f_n| d\mu \leq \mu(X) + \int |f_n|^2 = \mu(X) + C < \infty$. Since $|f_n| \rightarrow |f|$ a.e., also have $\int |f| \leq$ lim inf $_n \int |f_n| \leq \mu(X) + C$. Thus, $f_n, f \in L^1$, so that $|f_n - f| \in L^1$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Define $A_n := \{|f_n - f| > \epsilon\}$ and $|A_n| := \mu(A_n)$ for each $n$. We then immediately obtain $\int_{A_n^C} |f_n - f| d\mu \leq \epsilon \mu(X)$ for every $n$.

On the other hand, for every $n$, we see that if $|A_n|= 0$, then $\int_{A_n} |f_n - f| d\mu = 0$. Otherwise, if $0 < |A_n| \leq \mu(X)$, we obtain from Jensen's inequality that $\big(\frac{1}{|A_n|} \int_{A_n} |f_n - f|d\mu \big)^2 \leq \frac{1}{|A_n|} \big( \int_{A_n} |f_n - f|^2 d\mu \big) \leq \frac{1}{|A_n|} \big( \int_X |f_n - f|^2 d\mu \big)$, where by the Minkowski inequality, $\int |f_n - f|^2 d\mu = \|f_n - f\|_2^2 \leq [\|f_n\|_2 + \|f\|_2]^2 \leq [2\sqrt{C}]^2 = 4C$. Therefore, $\int_{A_n} |f_n - f|d\mu = \sqrt{|A_n|\int |f_n - f|^2 d\mu} \leq 2\sqrt{C}\sqrt{|A_n|}$.
Note that since $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. and $\mu(X) < \infty$, $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost uniformly by Egoroff, so that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure. Thus, for $n$ large enough we have $|A_n| < \epsilon$.

Hence, for $n$ large enough:

$\int_X |f_n - f| = \int_{A_n^C} |f_n - f| d\mu + \int_{A_n} |f_n - f| d\mu \leq \epsilon \mu(X) + 2 \sqrt{C}\sqrt{\epsilon}$. With $\epsilon$ arbitrary, it follows that $\int_X |f_n - f| d\mu \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it is that given $X$ is a finite measure space, if $\{f_n\}$  is a bounded sequence in $L^p(X)$ for $p>1$, this implies that $f_n$ are [uniformly integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability). And the result you are looking for follows from [Vitali Convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem).

Comment: One can see this is using Holder's inequality: $\int f_n 1_A d \mu \leq \| f_n \|_{L^p} \mu(A)^{1/q}$ where $1/p+1/q=1$. So the "$\delta$" that you need for the definition of uniform integrability is $(\varepsilon/C)^q$, where $C$ is the bound on $\| f_n \|_{L^p}$.